# Calculate Decibels from AudioRecorder in Android

Tags: java, android, audiorecord, amplitude, decibel

I am using the Android `AudioRecord` to get a continuous audio buffer. During the`read`, I want to evaluate the highest decibel from the buffer.

Below is the configuration of AudioRecord:

> sample rate = 16000; channels = 1; bits per sample = 16;

Reading the buffer in a byte array:

```
int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRateInHz, channelConfig, audioFormat);
// bufferSize is 1280 with sampleRateInHz = 16000, channelConfig = 16 and audioFormat = 2

int bytesRead;
byte[] fullBuffer = null;
byte[] auxBuffer = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

while(isRecording) {
  bytesRead = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
  if(fullBuffer == null) {
    fullBuffer = new byte[buffer.length];
    fullBuffer = buffer.clone();
  }
  else {
    auxBuffer = fullBuffer.clone();
    fullBuffer = new byte[buffer.length + fullBuffer.length];
    System.arraycopy(auxBuffer, 0, fullBuffer, 0, auxBuffer.length);
    System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, fullBuffer, auxBuffer.length, buffer.length);
  }
}
```

Converting this byte array to a short array:

```
public static short[] convertByteArrayToShortArray(byte[] byteArray) {
    short[] shortArray = new short[byteArray.length / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i += 2) {
      short sample = (short) ((byteArray[i] << 8) | byteArray[i + 1]);
      shortArray[i / 2] = sample;
    }
    return shortArray;
  }
```

Getting the Max Amplitde from the short array:

```
short[] shortBuffer = convertByteArrayToShortArray(fullBuffer);

double maxAmplitude = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < shortBuffer.length; i++) {
  short sample = shortBuffer[i];
  double amplitude = Math.abs(sample);
  if (amplitude > maxAmplitude) {
    maxAmplitude = amplitude;
  }
}
```

Calculating the decibel from the max amplitude:

```
double db = 20 * Math.log10(maxAmplitude / 32768);
```

The above is not returning realistic values for decibels. The deviation in value between total silence and loudness is none.

Below are some logs (note that the **Buffer** value is same for all logs):

> Buffer [B@25df3e4
>  Buffer Length 1280
>  Full Buffer [B@152c381
>  Full Buffer Length 28160
>  Short Buffer
> [S@e94bc26
>  Short Buffer Length 14080
>  Max Amplitude
> 32768.0
>  Decibel 0.0
>
> Buffer [B@25df3e4
>  Buffer Length 1280
>  Full Buffer [B@48074b2
>  Full Buffer Length 33280
>  Short Buffer
> [S@1ec1c03
>  Short Buffer Length 16640
>  Max Amplitude
> 32768.0
>  Decibel 0.0
>
> Buffer [B@25df3e4
>  Buffer Length 1280
>  Full Buffer [B@5f30f62
>  Full Buffer Length 33280
>  Short Buffer
> [S@ef998f3
>  Short Buffer Length 16640
>  Max Amplitude
> 32768.0
>  Decibel 0.0
>
> Buffer [B@25df3e4
>  Buffer Length 1280
>  Full Buffer [B@e040029
>  Full Buffer Length 33280
>  Short Buffer
> [S@876bfae
>  Short Buffer Length 16640
>  Max Amplitude
> 32768.0
>  Decibel 0.0

Please suggest what's wrong here.

Comment: Your decibel formula suggests that you may always be getting zero as your max amplitude for some reason.